# Serving images in C++ server

Tags: c++

I have a C++ linux server, with basic server sockets. Here's what i'm using to server png images:

```
string ms = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-type: image/png\r\n\r\n";
ifstream myfile("xampl.png", ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
string line;
char* memblock;
streampos size;
if(myfile.is_open()){
    size = myfile.tellg();
    memblock = new char [size];
    myfile.seekg (0, ios::beg);
    myfile.read (memblock, size);
    myfile.close();
}
ms.append(string(memblock));
cout << "\"" << ms << "\"" << endl;
char* msg = new char[ms.size()+1];
copy(ms.begin(), ms.end(), msg);
msg[ms.size()] = '\0';
int len;
ssize_t bytes_sent;
len = strlen(msg);
bytes_sent = send(new_sd, msg, len, 0);
```

I know i'm trying to read the png file as a binary file, but i have no idea what else to do.  When i telnet to this server, i get a response with weird characters which make me believe that i have served the file, but when i check it out in my browser, i get the image not found icon, in all browsers. Please help...

Comment: Dumping a file into a mem block, then into a string and then into a C string is not only a convoluted way of doing things, it's also buggy. C strings will end at the first '\0' character encountered, so your code will work fine with text files but will choke on binary ones.

Comment: No! As a binary file, into a memory block that will be passed straight to the output socket just after you sent the required headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let's start with the equivalent PHP code to get rid of the mess it is to do the same thing in C++

```
// send required headers as plain text
header("Content-type: image/png");

// read the image as a binary block
$img_data = file_get_contents("xample.png");

// send it
echo $img_data;
```

C++ equivalent:

```
string headers = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-type: image/png\r\n\r\n";
send (new_sd, headers.data(), headers.length(), 0);

ifstream f("xampl.png", ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
if(!f.is_open()) error ("bloody file is nowhere to be found. Call the cops");
streampos size = f.tellg();
char* image = new char [size];
f.seekg (0, ios::beg);
f.read (image, size);
f.close();

send (new_sd, image, size, 0);
```

Comment: No problem. Despite all the fanatics ready to burn me alive for this blasphemy, I still think C++ is a bloody messy language :)

Comment: Yes, except that you have to send appropriate headers. Various PHP and/or Apache docs will likely be a good source of information to see the kind of headers you should provide.

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck with your server.

Answer (score 1):

Converting `memblock` to a string is not going to work if it has embedded null characters, which it almost certainly does, and you don't pass the length. I'm not sure why you're doing all that faffing about with `char*`s and `std::string`s, but once you have your `memblock` and `size`, use them for `send`. If you want to prefix the response string, just `send` it first.